# Laravel:Passing variable from controller to view

Tags: laravel-4

```html
chatcontroller.php function returns variable to view:    
public function getChat()
    {
        $message = chat_messages::all();                    
        return View::make('home',compact($message));
    }   
this is my route:
Route::get('/getChat', array('as' => 'getChat','uses' => 'ChatController@getChat'));                                                                      
this is my home.blade.php:                                                           

@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Welcome to Home Page!</h2>
        <p> <a href="{{ URL::to('/logout') }}" > Logout </a></p>
        <h1>Hello <span id="username">{{ Auth::user()->username }} </span>!</h1>
        <div id="chat_window">
                
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="chat" class="typer" id="text" autofocus="true" onblur="notTyping()">
       
    </div>
<ul>
@foreach($message as $msg)
<li>
{{ $msg['sender_username']," says: ",$msg['message'],"<br/>" }}
</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/chat.js') }}"></script>

@stop
```

I am trying to send result returned by select query to view from controller.

when I do this from homecontroller.php then it works fine.
if I try to pass from controller which I have defined it gives error message as:Undefined variable.

I have used the extends \BaseController do i need to do anything else to access my controller variable from view.

please suggest some tutorial if possible for same.

Comment: Probably your route is not accessing your defined controller. You must change it to use the new controller instead of the HomeController

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: The problem should be in your routes. Show us some code, plz.

Comment: chatcontroller.php function returns variable to view:

Answer (score 1):

Verify the route to be sure it uses the new controller:

```
Route::get('user/profile', array('uses' => 'MyDefinedController@showProfile'));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all check your routes, as Matei Mihai says.
There are two different ways to pass data into your view;

```
$items = Item::all();

// Option 1
return View::make('item.index', compact('items'));

// Option 2
return View::make('item.index')->with('items', $items); // same code as below

// Option 3
View::share('item.index', compact('items'));
return View::make('item.index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
$this->data['items'] = Item::all();

return View::make('item.index', $this->data);
```